# Replacing all instances of a character in a string using python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

trying to replace all instances of a given character in a string with a new character. The following is my code:

```
def main():
    s='IS GOING GO'
    x='I'
    y='a'

   rep_chr(s,x,y)


def find_chr(s,char):
    i=0
    for ch in s:
        if ch==char:
            return (i)
            break        
        i+=1
    return -1
def rep_ch(s,x,y):
    result=""

    for char in s:

        if char == x:
            print(result=result+ y )        
        else:
            return char   
main()
```

Edited the code, but it is still replacing the first 'I' with 'a' and ignoring the second 'I'. Any suggestion?

Comment: It seems like you intended `range(len(s1))` instead of `range(s1)`.

Comment: I can't use any python methods. I basically have to build it from scratch.

Comment: Is this because you are doing an assignment? Otherwise there is no reason not to use python methods.

Comment: @cobra `range` is a python method :)

Comment: Actually, technically the `[]` operator is a method, since to use it it calls the `__getitem__` or `__getslice__` methods internally.

Comment: len and range are built in methods and I am allowed to use built in methods and nothing else.

Comment: `.replace` is built in to the `str` object.  Do you mean you can use built it *functions*?  Because really `len` and `range` are *functions*, not *methods*.  It's an important distinction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in range(s1):
```

Here `s1` is a string and you are passing it to `range` function, which expects only numbers as parameters. That is the problem. You should be using the length of the string instead

```
for i in range(len(s1)):
```

But, your actual problem can be solved with [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), like this

```
s='IS GOING GO'
x='I'
y='a'
print(s.replace(x, y))
```

If you want to solve without `str.replace`, you can do it like this

```
s, result, x, y ='IS GOING GO', "", "I", "a"
for char in s:
    if char == x:
        result += y
    else:
        result += char
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
aS GOaNG GO
```

The same program can be written like this as well

```
s, result, x, y ='IS GOING GO', "", "I", "a"
for char in s:
    result += y if char == x else char
print(result)
```

Comment: Sorry, can't use any python methods.

Comment: i changed the code, but it only replaces the first 'I' with 'a' and ignores the second 'I'.

Comment: @cobra Please edit the question and update with the changed code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. It helped a lot.